# Access Sql group by with concate column data

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I have table1

Table1

```
 PNAME      PBS    Vkg
   p1       ABC    2
   p2wt     ABC    3
   p3       EFG    1
   p3wtke   EFG    1
```

Group by

```
 Select PNAME, PBS,Sum(Vkg) As swt from table1 group by PNAME,PBS;
```

which gives me same thing like above table. But how do i concate PNAME if same PBS occur like

```
  PNAME       PBS    Vkg
   p1-p2wt    ABC    5
   p3-p3wtke  EFG    2
```

Answer (score 0):

For your particular example, this happens to work:

```
Select min(PNAME) & '-' & max(PNAME), PBS, Sum(Vkg) As swt
from table1
group by PBS;
```

I am not sure if this is a general solution to your problem, however.

Edit:

Use `iif()` to handle the case where the values are the same:

```
Select iif(min(Pname) = max(Pname), min(Pname),
           min(PNAME) & '-' & max(PNAME)
          ),
       PBS, Sum(Vkg) As swt
from table1
group by PBS;
```

Comment: Sam If your general problem have exactly two results for each `PBS` can work, but if have only one or more than two will have wrong answers.

Comment: @Linoff It gives me all PBS occurrences with PNAME concate if PBS same

Answer (score 0):

Here is a general solution:

```
declare @Table1 table(ID int identity(1,1), PNAME varchar(50), PBS varchar(50), Vkg int)
insert into @Table1
select PNAME, PBS, Vkg from Table1

declare @t table(PNAME varchar(100), PBS varchar(100));
declare @num int = 1
declare @pname varchar(100)=''
while(@num <= (select count(*) from @Table1))
    Begin
        set @pname=(select PNAME from @Table1 where ID = @num);
        while((select PBS from @Table1 where ID=@num)=(select PBS from @Table1 where ID=@num+1))
        begin
            Set @pname = @pname + (select PNAME from @Table1 where ID=@num+1)
            set @num = @num +1
        end
        insert into @t values(@pname, (select PBS from @Table1 where ID=@num));
        set @num = @num +1
    End
select t.PNAME, t.PBS, T1.Vkg from @t t
left join (select PBS, sum(Vkg) as Vkg from @Table1 Group by PBS) T1 ON t.PBS=t1.PBS
```